# Bing Map REST API does not return proper lat-long values

Tags: bing-maps, bing-api

When I am searching '藕舫路276号' in BING MAP, it is locating proper place. But when I am trying to invoke BING MAP REST API using the below request, I am not getting proper lat-long values.

[http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?countryRegion=CN&addressLine=藕舫路276号&key={my-bing-key}](http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?countryRegion=CN&addressLine=%E8%97%95%E8%88%AB%E8%B7%AF276%E5%8F%B7&key=%7Bmy-bing-key%7D)

I have also tried below query, but its returning wrong location data.

[http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?CountryRegion=CN&query=藕舫路276号&incl=queryParse&key={my-bing-key}](http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?CountryRegion=CN&query=%E8%97%95%E8%88%AB%E8%B7%AF276%E5%8F%B7&incl=queryParse&key=%7Bmy-bing-key%7D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing two different geocoding requests in one. structured and unstructured. `query` should only be used on it's own, when you add `CountryRegion` to the request, it might be interpreted as a structured request and the query parameter ignored.

Also try setting the `culture` parameter of the URL to `zh-Hans` or `zh-Hant` so that the geocoder knows your request is in Chinese and to call into the Chinese data provider for detailed Chinese map data.

Also, be sure to encode your query so that special characters don't cause issues in the request. This is a [best practice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/getting-started/bing-maps-api-best-practices#bing-maps-rest-service-tips-and-tricks).

Here is a modified version of your request.

http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?query=%E8%97%95%E8%88%AB%E8%B7%AF276%E5%8F%B7&incl=queryParse&culture=zh-Hans&key=

Comment: Thanks @rbrundritt for your support. It's working fine now !

Comment: I am getting a proper response when trying from localhost, but returning connection reset exception in my staging environment(HTTPS). Any suggestions? @rbrundritt

Comment: A connection reset exception would be caused by something in your HTTP requesting code. I've seen this before in other environments when calling any REST service. Do a search for this error for the server/language you are using and you will likely find lots of others who encountered this and have the solution. It's likely a simple setting in your requesting programming language.